# How to checkout a specified commit? (Natural method doesn't work)

Tags: git

Is there a **definitive, sure fire** way that does not depend on circumstances, to quietly, non-interactively, replace the contents of the working directory and of the index by a snapshot captured by a given `commit`, specified either explicitly or via a branch name?

Note that the natural method, namely

> `git checkout a_branch`

does not qualify as an answer to my question, because there are situations when it does not accomplish the desired effect, for instance if `a_branch` is the current branch (i.e. `HEAD' points at`a_branch`).

Comment: You're mixing terms here. If you're already on a specific branch on a specific commit you've already "checked out" that commit and possibly that branch. If you want to get rid of uncommitted changes and revert the working folder to the contents of the repository at that commit that's a different operation. Be sure you know what you ask for to get the right answers.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: 1. Why should I worry about which branch is checked out? Why can't I simply tell Git what is the desired end result that I wish to set up, and Git will take care of the details for me? 2. How can I revert the working folder to the contents of the repository at that commit?

Comment: You **can** tell git the command to execute in order to get the end result you want. The important part is that if you ask **here** how to do something, you will invariably get *human* responses as to how to accomplish that. If you then use the incorrect terms, you will get incorrect answers. Git won't magically understand that you meant to do something completely different, it will do what you told it to do.

Comment: The title of this question is misleading because you say "natural method doesn't work". We humans then go into troubleshooting mode and think "now why wouldn't git checkout actually check out the commit". Since you don't really want to check out a commit after all but to revert any local uncommitted changes, it is important to be precise, otherwise you will get the answer you got here now which if executed incorrectly will mess up your repository more than it will fix.

Comment: If, while reverting the working folder to the contents of the repository at that commit, do you also want HEAD to *be* at that commit? Or do you want to leave HEAD where it was, you just want to restore all the files from that commit?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I'd like to know how to accomplish both, please.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do this with a Git Reset --hard.

For example:
`git reset --hard <SOME-COMMIT>`

> Word of waring: All uncomitted changes will be destroyed!

Comment: This will also reset the branch to that commit (if you've checked out a branch), this is not recommended if the only point was to reset the HEAD. Make sure you're in a detached head state first to avoid messing with the branch.